# How do I make the bottom area of my grid grow into the bottom right corner?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I want to grow the div with the text of "Five" to cover the area below "Two and Three" in this grid. However, I'm not sure what to do beyond making the div having the property of "Flex:1". If you run the snippet below, you can see that "Five" is below only "Two".

```css
body{
    width: 100%;
}

 
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
    

.Five{
    flex: 1;
    background-color: blue;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="One">One</div>
        <div class="Two">Two</div>
        <div class="Three">Three</div>
        <div class="Four">Four</div>
        <div class="Five">Five</div>
      </div>
            
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `grid-column: 2 / 4` to .Five which will make that element span the 2nd and 3rd columns.